# Linked block doesn't complete

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I'm starting with TPL DataFlow.
I've the following working code created. the readFilesBlock is a **BufferBlock** 
It is filled like this:

```
public async void ReadItems(ITargetBlock<SourceCodeFile> target)
{
    foreach(var item in Source)
    {
        await target.SendAsync(item); //when To use post instead of sendasync? 
    }
}

target.Complete();
```

Now I cosume the BufferBlock (readFilesBlock) like this

```
while (await readFilesBlock.OutputAvailableAsync())
    {
        var file = await readFilesBlock.ReceiveAsync();

        ActionBlock<SourceCodeFile> action = new ActionBlock<SourceCodeFile>(item => storeResultsInBag(resultBag, item));
        await action.SendAsync(file);
    }
```

This Works fine.
Now I want to use the link Feature

I tried:

```
var storeFilesInBagAction = new ActionBlock<SourceCodeFile>(item => storeResultsInBag(resultBag, item));

readFilesBlock.LinkTo(storeFilesInBagAction);

await storeFilesInBagAction.Completion;
```

But this time i'll never get a completion.

What am I doing wrong?

When I'm not await the storefiles in Bagaction ,not items were returned.

Comment: 1. Avoid `async void`. 2. You don't need to create new `ActionBlock` for each file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, dataflow blocks do not propagate completion. This is by design; dataflows can represent any kind of mesh, including splits, joins, and loops (not just pipelines).

There is a [`PropagateCompletion` option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowlinkoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can set when linking that will propagate completion.

```
readFilesBlock.LinkTo(storeFilesInBagAction, new DataflowLinkOptions
{
    PropagateCompletion = true,
});
```

Comment: Thanks that was it. Btw can you give me any hint on good webcasts / tutorial on this topic?

Comment: There aren't any great tutorials that I know of. I did a [three-part intro on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/search/label/Dataflow) but it's not perfect. A more in-depth tutorial is the [original Introduction to TPL Dataflow](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14782) document.